# How $watch controller method in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have CKEDITOR, a controller and a directive. This is the method of the controller which should add ng-show and remove ng-hide from the `<span>`:

```
   $scope.deleteEditorAndSave = () ->
    angular.forEach CKEDITOR.instances, (editor) ->
      id = editor.element.getAttribute('data_id')
      text = editor.getData()
      field = editor.element.getNameAtt()

      html_field = $(editor.element.$)
      html_field.val(text)

      showing = editor.element.getAttribute('ng-show')
      console.log showing
      $timeout( ->
        html_field.trigger('input')
        $scope.save_field(text, id, field, 'no_call')
        editor.destroy()
        angular.forEach allClaims(), (claim) ->
          console.log "CLAIM", claim
          claim[showing.split('.')[1]] = false
      )
```

And I want to call this method from the directive. When I try to do this, the `<span>` element doesn't re-render. Does anyone know how this can be solved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its a strict NO NO to DOM manipulation within controller. Use directive, model and controller pattern to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the recommended practice is to resolve DOM in the directives, once thing that can help you is a directive with isolated scope, this will allow you to use `&` in your directives scope like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div user-name="" callme="enableEditor()"></div>
  <div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="enableEditor()">add</a>
  </div>
<script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.enableEditor = function() {
        alert("123");
    };  
}]);
myApp.directive("userName", function() {
    return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                value: "=userName",
                callme:"&"
            },
            template: '<div class="click-to-edit">' +
            '<a href="#" ng-click="callme()">Edit</a>' +
            '</div>'
        };
});
```

The attribute `callme="enableEditor()"` is used to pass the method to the scope directive, the directive scope uses `&` to indicate it is method `callme:"&"`.  Another example:

`method2="someMethod()"` like

```
scope: {
      value: "=userName",
      callme:"&",    
      method2:"&"
},template: '<div class="click-to-edit">' + '<a href="#" ng-click="callme()">Edit</a>' + '<a href="#" ng-click="Method2()">Save</a>' + '</div>'
```

This is the recommended way to communicate directives with controllers.